# Using PySpark to Count Number of Occurrences

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a PairedRDD that contains the Document ID as key, and a list of words in that document as the value.
E.g.

| DocID | Words |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | ["quick","brown","fox","lazy","fox"] |
| 002 | ["banana","apple","apple","banana","fox"] |

I managed to do a mapValues such that:

| DocID | Words |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | [("quick",1),("brown",1),("fox",1),("lazy",1),("fox",1)] |
| 002 | [("banana",1),("apple",1),("apple",1),("banana",1),("fox",1)] |

Is there a way to do a ReduceByKey() on just the Words?

| DocID | Words |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | [("quick",1),("brown",1),("fox",2),("lazy",1)] |
| 002 | [("banana",2),("apple",2),("fox",1)] |

I still need to maintain the structure such that counts are only applied within each Document only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count the number of words in each doc:

```
from collections import Counter

rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ("001", ["quick","brown","fox","lazy","fox"]),
    ("002", ["banana","apple","apple","banana","fox"])
])

counted = rdd.mapValues(lambda x: list(zip(Counter(x).keys(), Counter(x).values())))

counted.collect()
# [('001', [('quick', 1), ('brown', 1), ('fox', 2), ('lazy', 1)]),
#  ('002', [('banana', 2), ('apple', 2), ('fox', 1)])]
```

Another RDD only way:

```
from operator import add

result = rdd.flatMapValues(lambda x: x) \
            .map(lambda x: (x,1)) \
            .reduceByKey(add) \
            .map(lambda x: (x[0][0], [(x[0][1], x[1])])) \
            .reduceByKey(add)

result.collect()
#[('002', [('banana', 2), ('apple', 2), ('fox', 1)]), 
# ('001', [('brown', 1), ('fox', 2), ('lazy', 1), ('quick', 1)])]
```